# Munkres Chapter 1 Section 7 Exercise 8

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ denote the two element set $\{0,1\}$; let $X^\omega$ denote the set of all the binary sequences; and let $B$ denote the set of countable subsets of $X^\omega$.

Then how to see if $X^\omega$ and $B$ have the same cardinality?

Answer (score 5):

Let $b = \{ b_1, b_2, \dots \} \in B$ and write 
$$b_1 = (b_{11}, b_{12}, b_{13}, \dots)$$
$$b_2 = (b_{21}, b_{22}, b_{23}, \dots)$$
$$b_3 = (b_{31}, b_{32}, b_{33}, \dots)$$
$$\text{etc}$$

Now use the *zig-zag* pattern to form a new sequence :

$$s = (b_{11}, b_{21}, b_{12}, b_{13}, b_{22}, b_{31}, \dots)$$

Then the mapping $b \mapsto s$ is an injection of $B$ into $X^{\omega}$.

**EDIT** Following your comments, here is a more detailed description :

To see that $f : B \rightarrow X^{\omega}$ is an injection of $B$ into $X^{\omega}$, we must show that $f(b) = f(c) \Rightarrow b = c$.

Suppose that $f(b) = f(c) = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots)$.  Then, by definition of $f$ we have :
$$a_1 = b_{11} = c_{11}, \tag{a}$$
$$a_2 = b_{21} = c_{21}, \tag{b}$$
$$a_3 = b_{12} = c_{12}, \tag{c}$$
$$ \text{etc} $$
Thus, 
$$\begin{align} b & = \{b_1, b_2, \dots \}
\\ & = \{ (b_{11}, b_{12}, \dots), (b_{21}, \dots), \dots \}
\\ & = \{ (c_{11}, c_{12}, \dots), (c_{21}, \dots), \dots \} \tag{by (a),(b),(c)}
\\& = \{c_1, c_2, \dots \} 
\\& = c
\end{align}$$

The converse follows by the same (reverse) argument.

Comment: while it is intuitively clear that the map $b \mapsto s$ is an injection, how to demonstrate this rigorously?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud I've posted a more rigorous argument as an edit to my original answer.  Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Once you have had a chance to read my edit, note that the converse (reverse) argument gives an injection in the other direction.  Therefore $ f $ is a bijection and so the sets have equal cardinality.

Comment: @nwr you assumed $b\in B$ is an infinitely countable set. If $b\in B$ is a finite subset, then how do we map $b$ to an element of $X^{\omega}$? If $b\in B$ is a finite set, and $c\in B$ is an infinitely countable set, then does $f(b) = f(c)$ imply $b=c$? How to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

how about this case?

let B, C be elements in B(collection), which has countable subsets of x^omega.

let be B={ (1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,.....),

```
       (0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,...,) }
```

C={(1,0,0,1,1,0, ...),

(0,1,1,0,0...),

(1,0,0,1, ...)}

your representation identifying the elements in B(collenction),

i think that is not unique

your function gives us the same value of B, C(my example, B, C) so that the function is not injective.....

Comment: actually i have problem with this exercise.....
i guess the exercise must be solve by using schroeder-berstein theorem which is in that section exercise number 6.
but i 'm dying to making injection from the collection to x^omega....shi.......

Answer (score 0):

This sort of argument requires the axiom of choice to hold. But the place where we use the axiom of choice is relatively mild. Here are some helpful steps along the way:

1. Show that $(X^\omega)^\omega$ and $X$ have the same cardinality.
2. Find a surjection from $(X^\omega)^\omega$ onto $B$.
3. Find an injection from $X^\omega$ into $B$.
4. Look at the Cantor-Bernstein theorem.
5. Have a beer to celebrate a proof well done. (The beer can be replaced by anything of celebratory nature, of course.)

The axiom of choice gets in the place where we exchange the surjection from the 2nd step to an injection in the other direction. The existence of such injection implies, for example, the existence of an injection from $\omega_1$ into the real numbers, something we know is impossible without a smidgen of choice.

Comment: Asaf Karagila, This exercise is on p.52 and the axiom of choice is written on p.59. Munkres didn't know we need the axiom of choice to prove this exercise?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Asaf Karagila, Thank you very much for your comment.